# c/c++ epoll multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, epoll

I know there are many questions about this, yet I still couldn't find the answer that helps me.

Let's take a small tcp server with epoll and we want it to utilize as many cpu cores as possible. I've thought about 2 ways it could be done, but none of them worked really well.

1 - Each thread has its own epoll fd and in a "while(1)" loop uses "epoll_wait()" and processes the requests.

2 - Only one epoll fd and creating a new thread for each request when processing it.

In one single thread I could do around 25k req/s, so I was assuming the first method would help a lot, but in reality when I used 2 epoll fd the app could only process ~10k req/s. Obviously I didn't even consider a 2nd method a real one, it was meant to fail, so yeah.

So basically my question is: how should I implement multithreading so it can *really* utilize more cpu cores?

The socket is non-blocking, TCP_NODELAY, TCP_FASTOPEN set, and I'm using EPOLLET mode as well.

Comment: google "thread pool".

Answer (score 0):

To use multiple cores, you would want to split the process into different threads, and have each thread waiting on it's own file descriptor. However, in this case, if you are only waiting on a *single* file descriptor, simply multi-threading it and using blocking reads on each file descriptor may be more efficient. You can also affine different threads to different cores, as the scheduler will often try to place different threads on the *same* core (because their TLBs are the same), so using:

```
  int sched_setaffinity(pid_t pid,size_t cpusetsize,cpu_set_t *mask);
```

Would help you affine things separately. Obviously, if you have more FDs than CPUs, you are going to have to make tradeoffs.

Here's what I am thinking: If you have two threads (like you tried) that aren't CPU bound, but largley waiting on I/O, the scheduler will think "they both have the same TLB footprint, and are both just waiting on I/O - so I'll just leave them both on the same CPU". It's a logical thing to do, will give good CPU and cache performance, but you need less latency than this (because roughly speaking, OPS/sec = 1/Latency) - so lock those two threads to different cores with the command above - at least see what it does.

Comment: I'm checking htop and I can see it uses the 2 cores every time, it's just simply slow for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Please be more specific about how data being processed with your 1st option, is there any data synchronization between the fd(s) ? Maybe that's what lowering overall performance.

And for the other option, the more reasonable way to go is using 1 epollfd and calling epoll_wait on it in multiple threads. It's kinda more complicated but may give better performance for absolutely io bound apps given there are no (or little) data dependence between the fd(s).